# How to make the indentation more smart

Tags: indentation, indent

I'm using vim to code and I `set autoindent` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Now, if I code as below:

```
if (a == 1)
{|     // the cursor is here and I type ENTER
}
```

After typing the ENTER, the code becomes as below:

```
if (a == 1)
{
    |     // Now the cursor is here, it indented automatically
}
```

It works as expected.

However, if I code like this:

```
if (a == 1)
{
|}   // the corsor is here and I type ENTER
```

It will become:

```
if (a == 1)
{

|}   // the corsor is here
```

Then I type `k` to move the cursor up and it will become:

```
    if (a == 1)
    {
|       // the corsor is here now, this is NOT what I expected
    }
```

What I expect:

```
if (a == 1)
{
    |       // after typing `k`, the cursor will indent automatically
}
```

Well, this might not be a big issue but I still want to make it.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I use `UltiSnips` for this. The workflow is `if<tab>` --> change condition-->jump forward. Done.

Comment: `<c-f>` always resets the indentation and the cursor position on the current line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler solution is to create a small function and to map `<CR>` to this function:

```
function! Enter()

    " When the cursor is between 2 curvy braces
    if search('{\%#}', 'n')

        " new line and insert line above
        return "\<CR>\<C-o>O"
    endif

    " Otherwise, simple newline
    return "\<CR>"
endfunction

inoremap <CR> <C-r>=Enter()<CR>
```

This is actually what some auto tag closing plugins do.
(like `autopairs` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found another way to avoid this issue:

```
inoremap <C-v><Enter> <CR><C-o>O
```

So, if I code like this:

```
if (a == 1)
{|}    // the cursor is here with INSERT mode
```

Now I can type `<C-v><C-Enter>` to get what I expected.

If you have a better way, please feel free to pose your answer and I'll accept it.